# Топологическая сортировка графа

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Не могу понять почему граф сортируется именно так. Перевод правильный, там ошибки нет.

[image: Задача]

[image: Ответ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для большинства направленных ациклических графов (DAG) существует множество вариантов правильной топологической сортировки, все они удовлетворяют главному условию - зависимая задача выполняется позже, чем та, от которой она зависит.

Какой именно результат получится в каждом случае - зависит от порядка перечисления дуг и от деталей реализации